# How can I move logo to centre and top-search to left side of screen in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, frontend, header

I want to move header logo to centre and top. Search bar to the left side of screen as per show in screen shoot how can I do this using default.xml file

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your move tag using below code :

> app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME
> HERE}}/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
    <body>
        <move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="logo" />
    </body>  
</page>
```

Now, You need to update less code also :

```
.header.content {
    text-align: center;
    .block.block-search {
        float: left;
    }
    .logo {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }
    .minicart-wrapper {
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```